# angularjs ng-model doesn't work after using self defined directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

My json data looks like

> > [{name:"a", content:[{name:"b", content:[{name:"c", id:1}, {...}]}, {...}]}, {name:"...", content:[...]}]

and I want to put it into a select which "a" and "b" are all optionGroup, only "c" is option.
like this:

> > **a
> >
> >      -b**
> >      c

Sample jsfidle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sunny_jerry/SHxBp/

Seems "ngOptions" could not meet my requirement, so I define a directive like this:

```
<select class="compo-tree" x-compo-tree colleges="colleges" ng-model="choice"></select>

directive('compoTreeNew', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            colleges: "=colleges",
            choice: "=ngModel"
        },
        link: function($scope, elm){
            $scope.$watch("colleges", function(){
                angular.forEach($scope.colleges, function(college) {
                    elm.append($("<optgroup>").attr("label", college.name));
                    angular.forEach(college["departments"], function(department) {
                        var optGroup = $("<optgroup>").attr("label", '- ' + department.name);
                        angular.forEach(department['disciplines'], function(discipline) {
                            optGroup.append($("<option>").attr("value", discipline.id).text(discipline.name));
                            if (!$scope.choice) { $scope.choice = discipline.id; }
                        });
                        elm.append(optGroup);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

It works fine and I can see the scope changes when I select different options.

But I found that I could not set the initialize value of choice, and then I found I couldn't set any choice to control "select" at any time, choice seems become one-way binding but I need it became two-way binding.

Sample jsfidle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sunny_jerry/SHxBp/

How can I fix it?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that each element has only one scope. Since your `compoTreeNew` directive uses isolate scope, that's the only scope on the element and it's disconnected from parent scope. This might have a side effect of breaking the built-in ng-model/selectController functionality on that same element.

Comment: @darkporter Do you mean I need implement ng-model myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to make it work, just set a watcher on `choice`

```
$scope.$watch( 'choice', function( val ) {
    elm.val( val );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SHxBp/2/

Comment: Thanks for help, I noticed that an blank option will appear in the select and after you click it will gone, any idea about remove this blank option at first time?